# How to dynamicly load files in dynamic header.php

Tags: php, html

I have a problem so this is my index.php

```
<?php 
require "header.php";
?>

<main>
</main>

<?php 
require "footer.php";
?>
```

The problem is in header.php I am loading CSS and PHP files with paths and it all works in index page but when you go in other pages/directories then files won't load because directory to files is different I am trying to find out how to load those files even if directory changes.

this is the normal way I tried it won't work this is two examples

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
```

They both work on index page but on other pages they wont load.

Comment: Try using a slash in front of your paths i.e. href="/css/style.css" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use absolute urls.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<form action="/includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
```